# Viewing internal Spark Dataframe contents

Tags: debugging, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When debugging a spark program, I can pause the stack and look at the frame to see all the meta data of a DataFrame.  Partition metadata like input split, logical plan metadata, underlying RDD metadata, etc.  But I cannot see the contents of the DataFrame.  The DataFrame is another JVM somewhere on another node, or even on the same node (on a local training cluster).  So my question, does anyone use a way for troubleshooting, where they are looking at the contents of the DataFrame partitions the way the driver program can be debugged?

Comment: This is one thing I am looking too for.